# How to handle password expire in SSH.net

Tags: passwords, ssh.net

I uses SSH.net to connect to my Linux. Password expires every 30 days.
One of requirements is to reset the password automatically.

But it failed.

In response.error, it is always 
        Error   "WARNING: Your password has expired.\nPassword change required but no TTY available.\n"

Code Sample as below

class Program
    {
        String host = "host";
        int port = 22;
        String username = "user";
        String password = "passwd";
        String newpassword = "newpasswd";

```
    PasswordConnectionInfo connectionInfo;

    void HandlePasswordExpired(Object sender, AuthenticationPasswordChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        e.NewPassword = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(newpassword);
    }


    void Init()
    {
        connectionInfo = new PasswordConnectionInfo(host, username, password);

        connectionInfo.PasswordExpired += HandlePasswordExpired;

    }

    void TestConnection()
    {
        try
        {

            using (var client = new SshClient(connectionInfo))
            {
                client.Connect();
                var resp = client.RunCommand("ls -l /");
                Console.WriteLine("Resp -> {0}", resp.Result);
                client.Disconnect();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Program prog = new Program();
        prog.Init();
        prog.TestConnection();
    }
}
```